# TypeScript - get the declaring type from a static method

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to work out how to return the type that declares a static method. This should also work in the case of derived types.

```
class Animal {
    static getType(): any {
        // Here I want to return the type that declares this method,
        // In this case Animal.
        // For derived types, it should return i.e. Dog, Cat, etc.

        // I tried...
        // return this.prototype; // But this doesn't work.
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {

}

class Cat extends Animal {

}
```

Calling `getType()` on `Animal`, `Dog` and `Cat` respectively, should produce:

```
Animal.getType() // Animal
Dog.getType() // Dog
Cat.getType() // Cat
```

I'm not even sure it's possible, but if anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

As a side note - what I want to be able to do is use `getType()` to return the declaring type, so that I can iterate over the other static members of that type, essentially the equivalent of

```
Object.keys(Dog) // ["Poodle", "Labrador", "Husky"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it on my own...

```
static getType(): any {
    return Object
        .create(this.prototype)
        .constructor;
}
```